# String compare failing in mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql

This has thrown me.

```
mb_detect_order("UTF-8");
$str_firstName = ucwords(strtolower(trim($str_firstName)));
$str_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($str_firstName);
$str_firstName = mb_convert_encoding($str_firstName, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($str_firstName));
$str_sql="SELECT * FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClients cCC WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND cCC.firstName = '$str_firstName'";
echo "<br>str_sql= ".$str_sql."</br>";//works when cut and pasted into phoMyAdmin
$res = $mysqli->query($str_sql) or die("Line ".__LINE__.$mysqli->error);
$res->num_rows;
$res->data_seek(0);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
if ($res->num_rows>0) {
   //firstName exists
   }
```

`$str_firstName` is read in from a text file
`$str_sql` will find records if cut and pasted into phpMyAdmin but not when run from php.
I have tried LIKE, BINARY and a variety of COLLATE statements in the sql. 
Of 30 plus names that are in the text file and have matches in db6901371_clients.costCentreClients it only returns a match for 1.

Comment: Could you give an example of a name not giving proper results?

Comment: SELECT * FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClients cCC WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND BINARY cCC.firstName = 'Yossefate'
returns NULL while SELECT * FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClients cCC WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND BINARY cCC.firstName = 'Natalia' returns TRUE while both names are on the database

Comment: Is _Ypssefate_ spelled exactly how it is displayed here? No special characters like accents or so and case correct? Did you check for invisible characters like blanks inside the database? And what does `SELECT * FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClients cCC WHERE cCC.firstName LIKE '%Yossefate%'` give you?